# Something wrong with the model I imported

Tags: objects

Okay so to start off I am somewhat of a noob when it comes to working with 3D but it's something I've been wanting to get into for years. I've been trying out two different 3D programs with one of them being Blender, the other is Vroid which is a relatively powerful tool that allows you to create your own character and do some major edits. Sadly the hair tool is crap for lack of a better term so I figured I would just transfer it to Blender. Vroid will only save the file as VRM format so I made a copy and changed it to GLB to open it in paint 3D then exported it as an FBX and imported it into Blender but this is what I got.[image]

What the heck are these orange lines? Why is my model upside down? And why is it ridiculously small? I had to use the scaling tool to zoom it or else you can't see it at all.

Comment: The orange lines are empties. It is small, because the scale is not consisted on fbx import/export between these applications. It is upside down, because the global *Up* axis is not consistent btween these application in fbx import/export.

Comment: Blender 2.8 can import glTF (or GLB) directly — it may be worth trying that to remove one step from the process.

Comment: This video has all of the links you need. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXGX3-a6OGc